# Python Django using wsgi.py with apache2 loads filter fields out of order every restart

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi

I have a django app that works just fine when running the python manage.py runsever command locally. When I tried to migrate it and modified my apache config file to use wsgi.py, everything works except for one page where the django filter fields are shuffled above a django table. Every time I restart the apache server, the filter fields are shuffled again in a new order. The local server always displays the filter fields in the correct order. Does anyone know why this is happening?

local server using python runserver command
[image]

apache server using wsgi
[image]

apache2.conf

```
    WSGIDaemonProcess /SeedInv python-home=/path/to/Software/anaconda3/envs/Django python-path=/path/to/WebServer/SeedInv
    WSGIProcessGroup /SeedInv
    WSGIScriptAlias /SeedInv /path/to/WebServer/SeedInv/SeedInv/wsgi.py process-group=/SeedInv

    <Directory /path/to/WebServer/SeedInv/SeedInv>
    <Files /path/to/WebServer/SeedInv/Seedinv/wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>

    Alias /static "/path/to/WebServer/SeedInv/static"
    <Directory "/path/to/WebServer/SeedInv/static">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /media "/path/to/WebServer/SeedInv/media"
    <Directory "/path/to/WebServer/SeedInv/media">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/anaconda3/envs/Django/lib/python3.6/site-packages')
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "SeedInv.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

filters.py

```
class GenoFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Genotypes
        fields = {'parent_f_row': ['icontains'],
                  'parent_m_row': ['icontains'],
                  'parent_f_geno': ['icontains'],
                  'parent_m_geno': ['icontains'],
                  'genotype': ['icontains'],
                  'seed_count': ['lt', 'gt'],
                  }
```

tables.py

```
class GenotypesTable(tables.Table):
    export_formats = ['tsv']

    class Meta:
        model = Genotypes
        template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap.html'
```

views.py

```
def InventoryTable(request):
    queryset = Genotypes.objects.all()
    f = GenoFilter(request.GET, queryset=queryset)
    table = GenotypesTable(f.qs)
    RequestConfig(request, paginate={'per_page': 25}).configure(table)

    export_format = request.GET.get('_export', None)
    if TableExport.is_valid_format(export_format):
        exporter = TableExport(export_format, table)
        return exporter.response('table.{}'.format(export_format))

    return render(request, 'Inventory/index.html',
                           {
                            'table': table,
                            'filter': f,
                            })
```

models.py

```
# Genotype database model
class Genotypes(models.Model):
    """list of current genotypes"""
    parent_f_row = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                                    validators=[],)
    parent_m_row = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                                    validators=[],)
    parent_f_geno = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                                     validators=[],)
    parent_m_geno = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                                     validators=[],)
    genotype = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                                validators=[],)
    seed_count = models.IntegerField(validators=[], default=0)
    actual_count = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    experiment = models.CharField(max_length=200,
                                  validators=[],
                                  blank=True,)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=300,
                                validators=[],
                                blank=True,
                                )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.genotype

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Genotypes"
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Until Python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6), you shouldn't rely on dictionaries being ordered. You can use an `OrderedDict` if the order of the keys is important.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class GenoFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Genotypes
        fields = OrderedDict([
            ('parent_f_row', ['icontains']),
            ('parent_m_row', ['icontains']),
            ('parent_f_geno', ['icontains']),
            ('parent_m_geno', ['icontains']),
            ('genotype', ['icontains']),
            ('seed_count', ['lt', 'gt']),
        ])
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Do you know why I only see that issue on wsgi.py with apache and not the local server?

Comment: No, I'm not sure why, unless you were running a different version of Python in development that does order dictionaries.

Comment: Interesting, wsgi.py is using the same conda env as the local Django server. Regardless, thanks for the help!